# why if not satisfying this statment?

Tags: swift

```
var names=["adlin","betro","subash"]

 if names[0]<names[0...]{

    print("adlin is always greater than subash")
      }
```

I know that if statement evaluates the only condition,  So I used this doubtful approach

Comment: What do you want the if statement to do?

Comment: my aim is not to get the output but to get an idea of working Thanks

Comment: Can you ask a specific question? It is not clear what you want as an answer.

Comment: Is names[0]<names[0...]  is a condition ? if not what is that?

Comment: It's a condition that doesn't compile because you can't compare a String to an ArraySlice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is `names[0]<names[0...]` is a condition ?

It is not a valid condition. `names[0...]` is a slice of the `names` array, and `names[0]` is a `String`. `String`s cannot be compared to a slice of an array. This notion makes little sense, doesn't it? Which is bigger - "adlin" or the array ["adlin","betro","subash"]? There is no answer.

You seem to want to compare the first and last element, in which case, you should do this:

```
if names.first! > names.last!
```